# Looking for advice on where to start with event receivers

Tags: event-receivers, sharepoint-on-prem

I am working on a solution that will require to detect when a page is created on prem (sharepoint 2016) and then use information from the page to create a list item online (o365 sharepoint)

My original approach would be to create an event listener that would listen for an item being published and then run, however I cannot find any specific references to setting up event receivers for 2016, mainly for 2010- Am I missing something?

I would appreciate if anyone who has managed to get an event listener in 2016 could point me in the right direction, or if my approach is not feasible if you could let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 approaches you can take. 
1. SharePoint add-in model - a new way of dealing with SP development

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/event-receiver-and-list-event-receiver-sharepoint-add-in

2. SharePoint full trust solution. The old way full trust solution. Most of guidance you will find on SP2010-13 will be applicable to this model in SP2016 but if you want to make your solution future proof (that is beyond SP2019 which still supports full trust solution) you need to go with option 1.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/sharepoint/how-to-create-an-event-receiver?view=vs-2017

The linked articles should give you a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction and explaining the difference between the two approaches for me :)